# Find attached images for one post type

Tags: posts

I would like to query for images attached to ALL posts of certain custom post type (e.g. 'gallery').

I can't see a way to do this by using only WP_Query. The workaround would be to query for all posts of a custom post type, then get the attachments and stuff everything together. But i don't think that this would be a good solution, because you end up doing multiple queries for something that should be done in one.

Please help =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and replace `custom-post` with your custom post type.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom-post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
        while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
            $image_query->the_post();
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good snippet, but I think it would be better if you use `get_posts()`

Comment: If you check the core files `get_posts()` itself instantiates a new WP_Query object. So that's why I prefer using `WP_Query()` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not what i need: I want a loopable list of all the images which are attached to any posts of a certain type, regardless to which post they belong. I can see that your way does roughly the same, but it does not give a single query for all images. I used a custom SQL-query for this now.

Comment: Query inside a loop, not a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

I have added rand and posts_per_page to the last answer

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom-post', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'orderby'=>'rand' ) );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
        while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
            $image_query->the_post();
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() );
        }
    }
}
```